# how to debug node apollo server with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webpack, apollo-server

I'm trying to debug an express apollo server app and I'm struggling to work out whats wrong. I've got a web pack build with source maps enabled and loader options debug set to true.

My npm script which outputs my webpack build and a url to the debugger

```
"debug": "node --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config ./webpack.dev.js"
```

I go to the debugger through `chrome://inspect` and I can view my code but when I send requests through `http://localhost:8080/graphiql` nothing happens within the debugger and the request goes through as normal.

here's my webpack config

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const StartServerPlugin = require("start-server-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./server.js"],
  watch: true,
  mode: "development",
  target: "node",
  node: {
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: ["webpack/hot/poll?1000"] })],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              presets: [["env", { modules: false }], "stage-0"],
              plugins: ["transform-regenerator", "transform-runtime"]
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new StartServerPlugin("server.js"),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: '[name].js.map'
    }),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": { BUILD_TARGET: JSON.stringify("server") }
    })
  ],
  output: { path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"), filename: "server.js" }
};
```

My question is there any extra hoops i need to go through to make it work with a graphql server have i got source maps set up correctly?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by having a node process and running the webpack config in parrell using nodemon and concurrently

> https://github.com/remy/nodemon
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

`"debug": "concurrently \"webpack --config ./webpack.dev.js\" \"nodemon --inspect=9229 ./dist/server.js\""`

I also added 
  `devtool: 'eval-source-map'` to my webpack confiuration to enable sourcemaps.

I also removed the start server plugin from the webpack config to essentially have webpack just building and nodemon serving.